# Which font for a tactics video game?

Tags: font-recommendation

I want to create various titles to use on books, web site and packaging in general for a video game that is of the squad based tactic type and in the Tron like, uncluttered dark and light blue style.

I want to convey the ideas of tactic/strategy and combat, with a little touch of hi-tech.

Comment: Legit question I suppose, but I just dont like these questions as.. its not like you cant find fonts.. its just that you dont know a font that would fit in this case. So, anyone answering is more or less shooting in the wind and guessing if this is what you want cause there is no exact answer. **Only you know what you want.**

Comment: @Lollero quite precise though

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: @e100 around 0€ :-D

Comment: Tron style... dark and light blue... **Frozen Synapse?**

Comment: I do not think I understand this: you are going to have books, packaging etc in your game. These objects should  obviously not have the same font! They _could_ generally belong in the same group, but in my world, there should be a wide variety.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dafont.com to download a free font that will fit the style you are looking for. Use the distorted, eroded, stencil, and techno categories.

I use this site all the time. The selection is great and you can preview the font as you browse by giving it a string to preview with (aka the text you'd want to format.)

Be aware some fonts may have restrictive licenses.

Here are links below to help you search:

(Techno Scifi)

http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=303

(Stencil/Army)

http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=114

"Font shopping" is one of my favorite things to do on Dafont.com! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a perfect font out there for what you want. The trick is knowing all the obscure places to check. I did some hunting for you - and though I have no affiliation with these guys, it seems they always have a good solution when I can't find a good solution. Check out the "Science" font they've used... I think it works perfect for your described application.

http://www.houseind.com/fonts/simian/fontspecimens

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct was some stencil stuff, but then I remembered how much I don't like those.

I'd do this:
http://www.google.com/webfonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Monofett

It reminds me of a stencil font without being a stencil font, and it also looks like typewriter keys, which makes me think of keyboards, which makes me think of computers. Boom, that's the *Apples to Apples* method of graphic design ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should look through font options on a font browsing website, such as  Myfonts.com. You can use their tag system to find the style you're looking for. For example, [search for fonts tagged futuristic](http://new.myfonts.com/search/tag%3afuturistic/fonts/).

[Eurostile](http://new.myfonts.com/search/eurostile/) is my go-to font when looking for a clean, easy to read, but "futuristic" looking font.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct would be to go with Terminal/Courier/monospace style fonts, to evoke the feeling of being at the dashboard of a command center.

Answer (score -3):

If you plan to use it on so many places, you better stick with some more legible typeface

Here is one I designed, that may be fit to you:

http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/boris-marinov/smallstep-pro/